# How to avoid an implicit "return" in coffeescript in conditional expressions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, deferred, promise

I am implementing a function that has deferred value to return and within the function I have many nested conditional expressions:

e.g.:

```
deferred = Q.defer()
FS.readFile("foo.txt", "utf-8", (error, text) ->
    if error
      deferred.reject(new Error(error))
    else
      deferred.resolve(text)
)
return deferred.promise
```

which than will be compiled into:

```
var deferred;

deferred = Q.defer();

FS.readFile("foo.txt", "utf-8", function(error, text) {
  if (error) {
    --> return <-- deferred.reject(new Error(error));
  } else {
    --> return <-- deferred.resolve(text);
  }
});

return deferred.promise;
```

I need only the last return, but not the if/else returns (i.e. **--> return <--** in the compiled code)

How can I avoid such a behavior (implicit returns where they are do not needed) of the coffeescript compiler?

Comment: This isn't the problem you think it is. The returns in question are returning from the inner callback function. This is desirable behaviour, and it's not interfering with your outer function's `return` in any way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Coffeescript automatically returns the result of the last expressions, so if you don't want it to return the results of the `if` then you need to add another expressions. In this case, just add `return`.

```
FS.readFile "foo.txt", "utf-8", (error, text) ->
  if error
    deferred.reject new Error(error)
  else
    deferred.resolve text
  return
```

Also, `error` is already an `Error` object, so you can just reject it directly.

```
deferred.reject(error)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but it looks for me like it will be compiled in "if/else expression following by return();" and than all the other code

Comment: @static Yep, and that's totally fine.

Comment: I mean it looks for me like will be compiled into:

`var deferred;

deferred = Q.defer();

FS.readFile("foo.txt", "utf-8", function(error, text) {
  if (error) {
    deferred.reject(new Error(error));
  } else {
    deferred.resolve(text);
  }
});

return;

return deferred.promise;`

So like two returns after a function

Comment: @static Are you sure your indentation is correct? It definitely shouldn't come out like that.

Comment: ok, because of the indentation it will be one return in the function and one return out there. but still, I find it little bit weired...
But really, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can't, exactly. You can either ignore them when not needed (which is the most common thing to do) or provide an explicit alternative by adding an additional statement at the end of the function. I think trying to do this all the time in your code base is fighting a war against the language you cannot win, so my personal recommendation is just accept Mr. Ashkenas's implicit return and go on your merry way.

```
fs.readFile "foo.txt", "utf-8", (error, text) ->

  # postfix style if statement here avoids the else
  # of course, the value returned you may not like, so 
  # you probably won't use this style, but my boilerplate for
  # error handling is
  # return callback(error) if error

  return deferred.reject(new Error(error)) if error
  deferred.resolve(text)

  # Here you can add an explicit return like
  return

  # or some other expression
  null

  # or 'this' in cases where chainability might be nice
  this

  # or so you don't accidentally delete this statement later thinking it is
  # useless
  return null
```

any of those forms will work, but in practice I don't see these commonly

Comment: Thank you! it is really a little bit weired to run into such a situation with a return statement

Comment: It's unfamiliar, but over time it will become familiar and probably won't bother you. I've never heard experienced coffeescripters mention this as troublesome.

Comment: Because it's not troublesome. The inner returns have no baring on the outer function. Ignore them.

Comment: But the inner return really does matter. See http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/why-i-hate-implicit-return-in-coffeescript.html and http://awardwinningfjords.com/2012/05/08/beware-coffeescript-comprehensions.html for why.

Comment: Because that's the way Coffeescript works, I have formed a habit of typing a 'return' immediately each time after typing '->' and a carrige return.

Answer (score 0):

i always do it like this:

```
f = ->
  deferred = Q.defer()
  FS.readFile ..., ( error, text ) ->
    return deferred.reject error if error?
    deferred.resolve text
  return deferred.promise
```

the first `return` is there to stop execution, not to return a value.

you still get an additional (and meaningless) `return` in your JS from the last line of the callback; to avoid that one, insert an additional `return null` (or simply `return` if you prefer that).

i'm not sure i like CoffeeScript's implicit `return` insertion; it might be claimed that 'explicit is better than implicit'. also, it could be argued that the first `return` shouldn't be a `return` but another keyword, like, say, `stop` or `finish` or somesuch.

as an unrelated sidenote, i haven't observed any noticeable advantage when using promises. to the contrary, i found them quite intrusive in my code, what with those `deferred`s and other concepts that are put on top of asynchronous programming.