# Using $provide to mock a service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

In the answer given by https://stackoverflow.com/a/22069389/270511,
can someone explain why you call $provide.value() and not $provide.service() to mock a service?

Answer (score 1):

`$provide.value` simply returns the value that you give when requested by the injector. You could also mock the service with `$provide.service`, but you would have to write a bit more code (returning an object with a `$get` method) that's not really necessary when just linking a simple function.

In other words, neatness/laziness!