# How to properly reference service in angularjs jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Here is an example:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('my-app'));

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _sessionParams_, _$httpBackend_, _pclnABTesting_){...}));
```

inside a jasmine unit test, we usually saw this sort of `_service_` inside the inject for `angular.mock`.

But I am still not sure how this works?

`For example, the parameter _myService_ would be resolved as the reference myService. Since it is available in the function body as myService, we can then assign it to a variable defined in an outer scope.`

In the [official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject), it say above, however, does it means, ANY service that is inside already injected module, we should always reference like `_MyServiceName_`? How exactly this `MyServiceName` is getting from? Should we do something before we inject it? That's where I got confused.

Answer (score 0):

Convention to add underscores was introduced to ease setup of unit tests. Usually you will have names without underscores used in tests like:

```
var fooService, barService;

beforeEach(inject(function(_fooService_, _barService_) {
  fooService = _fooService_;
  barService = _barService_;
}));

it('should blah blah', function() {
  fooService.foo();
  // assert, assert, assert
});
```

if `beforeEach` parameters doesn't have underscores then you would not be able to use single names like `fooService` in unit tests.

```
var fooService, barService;

beforeEach(inject(function(fooService) {
  // hmm how to setup outher variable fooService?
}));
```

But to be pragmatic sometime you just need a service to call some action before unit tests, e.g.

```
beforeEach(inject(function(bazService, _fooService_) {
  bazService.clearSelection();
  fooService = _fooService_;
}));
```

in that case adding underscores would be overkill, so when you need it you may add underscores, and when you don't you may leave then. Thats how I see it.

For inject to work properly you must load your module before executing your test:

```
beforeEach(module('app'));
```

A great tutorial how to write AngularJS tests is in official documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing (if you want just code - scroll to testing controller section, same approach goes for testing service).

Comment: so underscore is really a jasmine syntax, that may apply for any js app testing. so its not really unique for angular. is that right?

Comment: so basically the dependencies that the actual app has, can't really be injected for real, but we have to MOCK them accordingly. right? we can't really inject the actual dependencies?

Comment: @Chen No, no - it's angular inject syntax and doesn't have anything with Jasmine - I will edit my answer

Comment: Still a bit confused. so when the `app` is loaded by `beforeEach(module('app'));
`, does it means, all its dependencies, the actual dependencies, are available for reference as well? so if we did `_fooService_`, then the actual service of `fooService` is `_fooService_`?

Comment: Yes after `beforeEach(module('app'))` all services provided by that module will be available for injection (use in inject). If app module has dependencies on other  non angular modules you must load them too. Exactly `_fooService_` will represent `fooService` from `app` module

Comment: ah so, if I want to mock the `_fooService_` instead of actual one, I can then override it by a fake one inside the `it()`. correct? :)

Comment: Note  that you can also use `this` in a jasmine test which allows you to bypass the `_service_` paradigm:  https://gist.github.com/traviskaufman/11131303

Comment: Here is how you mock service: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274274/how-do-you-mock-a-service-in-angularjs-when-unit-testing-with-jasmine, generally you should mock before inject but after loading module

Comment: @Chen -- If you actually want to mock the entire service, I usually do it at the module level:  `testModule = angular.module('testMod', ['my-app']).value('serviceNameToMock', mockService); module(testModule.name)'`

Comment: @mgilson thanks for the tips :) when you do this way, does it means that `mockService` is the actual service included in the `testModule.name`? or I should put that actual service name in to `serviceNameToMock`? Thanks. Because I really want to know if I can actually inject the real services that I injected as dependencies into the test itself.

Comment: If you don't need to use the service and only need to inject it for your tests, then it's ok to write it with underscores.