# How to unit test $uibModal in Jasmine? (unit testing injected library)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-ui-bootstrap

So I am using $uibModal from bootstrap and I have the following code in my AngularJS controller:

```
vm.openPopup = function() {
  $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'popup.html',
    controller: function() {
       var modal = this;

       modal.hi = function() {
         // some code here
       }
    }
  });
};
```

How would I go about calling the modal.hi function in Jasmine and unit testing it to make sure it works correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main problem with testing this code is that you've basically "buried" an anonymous function (`modal.hi`) inside of *another* anonymous function (`$uibModal.open`). That makes it pretty tricky to test.

You've got a few options: a.) you can mock the `$uibModal` service, b.) you can restructure your code, or c.) you could just drop your `hi` function onto the `vm` itself, and then call it from your tests. I think the last option would be the most expedient, but here are some examples of all three approaches.

### Option 1: Mock the `$uibModal` service

```
describe('Test vm.openPopup', function () {
  var mockUibModal = {
    open: function(options){
      var ctrl = options.controller();
      // call your `hi` function:
      ctrl.hi();
    }
  };

  beforeEach(function(){
    module(function($provide){
      $provide.value('$uibModal', mockUibModal);
    });
  });
});
```

And from there, you could call your `vm.openPopup` method, and go about testing the results. Note that the `module` function comes from [angular-mocks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock), which you'll need to install/include with your tests. Related question: "[How do you mock a service in AngularJS when unit testing with jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274274/how-do-you-mock-a-service-in-angularjs-when-unit-testing-with-jasmine)"

### Option 2: Restructure your code

Here's a pattern that I frequently use, which involves shifting the logic/functions you wish to test into a separate factory:

```
var app = angular.controller('YourController', function ($uibModal, MyHelperFactory) {
  var vm = this;
  var modal;

  var helper = MyHelperFactory(vm, modal);

  vm.openPopup = function () {
    $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'popup.html',
      controller: function () {
        modal = this;
        modal.hi = helper.hi;
      }
    });
  };
});

app.factory('MyHelperFactory', function () {
  return function (vm, modal) {
    return {
      hi: function () {
        // some code here, maybe it needs to reference the `vm` object, whatever...
      }
    }
  };
})
```

The benefit of this approach is that you can test the `MyHelperFactory` on its own, without needing to instantiate `YourController`, and without needing to involve the `$uibModal` service. This is typically my favorite approach: no inline/anonymous functions - get that logic into helper factories, and out of my controllers.

### Option 3: Drop the `hi` function onto `vm`

```
var app = angular.controller('YourController', function ($uibModal, MyHelperFactory) {
  var vm = this;

  // this pattern allows your function to be scoped with the not-yet-existing `modal` object
  vm.hi = function (modal) {
    return function () {
      // some code here
    }
  };

  vm.openPopup = function () {
    $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'popup.html',
      controller: function () {
        var modal = this;
        modal.hi = vm.hi(modal);
      }
    });
  };
});
```

And from there, you can just test it by calling `vm.hi` from within your tests. I call this approach "dirty" because it adds the `hi` method to the `vm` object, and I generally avoid adding any properties to the `vm` object that aren't actually needed on the controller scope. In this case though, we're breaking that rule because it's the quickest/easiest way to "expose" this function that you wish to test.

Comment: I figured it would be pretty hard.  All these are great options though, thanks!